# Using re.findall to find string but to store int value from a file

Tags: python

I have a file log.txt That file has these lines, given below

```
Sett S=1
Stage Tmsec;
NP=81
NC1=3
```

I have a python code to just get the values of Sett S,NP,NC1 in the form of list.

I came up with a term named re.findall but i was able to get the exact value using re.findall but not able to stored value as int instead of string.

When I try to convert the list into integer list it throws a error saying 'str' error.

Couldn't able to come up with solution so far.

Comment: maybe if `=` in line print `line.split('=')[1]`?

Comment: it is more like work of regex with compiler construction

Answer (score 1):

Use **Regex**:

**Ex:**

```
import re
data = """Sett S=1
Stage Tmsec;
NP=81
NC1=3
Sett S=2
Stage Tmsec;
NP=82
NC1=4
Sett S=3
Stage Tmsec;
NP=83
NC1=5"""


Sett_S = re.findall("Sett S=(.*)", data)
NP = re.findall("NP=(.*)", data)
NC1 = re.findall("NC1=(.*)", data)

for i in zip( Sett_S, NP, NC1 ):
    print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
('1', '81', '3')
('2', '82', '4')
('3', '83', '5')
```

Comment: when I read the list , I noticed that the data type of the list was string but not int. It would be very helpful if the list containing datatype was int instead of str.

Comment: `print( list(map(int, i)) )`

Comment: Yep , unfortunately the log.txt file is in GB having similar string through them many times. The Cycles are too much, any way to low the load.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: s = '''Sett S=1
   ...: Stage Tmsec;
   ...: NP=81
   ...: NC1=3'''

In [2]: import re
In [8]: m = re.search(r'S=(\d+).*NP=(\d+).*NC1=(\d+)', s, flags=re.S)

In [9]: m.groups()
Out[9]: ('1', '81', '3')

In [10]: m.group(1)
Out[10]: '1'

In [11]: m.group(2)
Out[11]: '81'

In [12]: m.group(3)
Out[12]: '3'
```